# Need to perform push operation in mongodb is not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, roles

I have some action they are View,edit,delete,add for each pages.

```
var roleprivilege = {
             'role_name' : req.body.role_name,
             'add':req.body['add'],
             'del':req.body['del'],
             'view':req.body['view'],
             'edit':req.body['edit'],
               }
```

I am using findOneAndUpdate

```
mongo.role.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': id},roleprivilege,{upsert: true,new : true},function(err, response) {
                console.log("Inserted");
            });
```

Its working good , but i need to store all the add,del,edit,view inside role. I tried like this

```
var roleprivilege = {
             'role_name' : req.body.role_name,
             'role':{
             'add':req.body['add'],
             'del':req.body['del'],
             'view':req.body['view'],
             'edit':req.body['edit']
              }
           }
```

Here the problem is if i choose only one value in action it is store like a string

And my view is here

```
        <div class="col-md-12 role_class" ng-repeat="menu in privilege_menu" >
          <div class="col-md-2">{{menu}}</div>
          <div class="col-md-10" ng-int="{{l_name =( menu|lowercase)}}">
            <span class="role_checkbox">  <label class="control control--checkbox">View
              <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="check_role(l_name,'view')" name="view" value="{{menu|lowercase}}" />
               <div class="control__indicator"></div>
              </label></span>
             <span class="role_checkbox"  > <label class="control control--checkbox">Add

                  <input type="checkbox"  name="add" value="{{menu|lowercase}}"  />
                   <div class="control__indicator"></div>
               </label></span>
             <span class="role_checkbox">  <label class="control control--checkbox">Edit
                  <input type="checkbox" name="edit" value="{{menu|lowercase}}" />
                   <div class="control__indicator"></div>
               </label></span>
             <span class="role_checkbox">  <label class="control control--checkbox">Delete
                  <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="{{menu|lowercase}}" />
                   <div class="control__indicator"></div>
               </label></span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I need an output in below format

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("592817d6f6d6dd35c381bb0d"), 
    "role_name" : "TSE", 
    "role" : {
        "view" : [
            "dashboard", 
            "settings", 
            "users", 

        ], 
        "add" : [
            "vehicles", 
            "customers", 
            "reports"
        ], 
        "edit" : [
            "users"
        ]
    }
}
```

My req.body looks like this

```
{ role_name: 'SA',
  view: [ 'dashboard', 'users', 'settings' ],
  add: 'users',
  edit: 'users',
  del: [ 'users', 'settings' ] }
```

Comment: How does the req.body object looks like ?

Comment: Thank you for the response                                                                    
  My req.body looks like this{ role_name: 'SA',
  view: [ 'dashboard', 'users', 'settings' ],
  add: 'users',
  edit: 'users',
  del: [ 'users', 'settings' ] }

Comment: I have updated in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the req.body does not use a list object when there is only one element eg:

```
view: [ 'dashboard', 'users', 'settings' ], 
add: 'users', instead of add: ['users']
```

You need to improve the creation of the variable roleprivilege to handle this case before inserting it in mongoDB.

you want roleprivilege to look like this when you print it:

```
{
   'role_name' :'SA',
   'role':{
   'add': ['users'],
   'del': [ 'users', 'settings' ],
   'view':[ 'dashboard', 'users', 'settings' ],
   'edit':['users']
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you I fixed the problem